# Magento attribute dropdown into fuzzy search

Tags: jquery, magento, fuzzy-search

I'm working on a Magento extension, which should ideally support versions as low as 1.5-1.6.

I've created a custom attribute (programatically as a part of the module) and it's a select type so it naturally renders a drop down.

I wonder, is there anyway to override that behaviour and make it render my own control which I have designed with help of jQuery (it's a drop down with fuzzy search functionality.) Or maybe there is a way to make the default Magento drop down into a fuzzy search.

I need it to be a fuzzy search because the list of values which can be selected are huge and a fuzzy search makes the selections much faster.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use `$installer->addAttribute(...)` for attribute creation? If yes - this allow you to set next options inside:

1. 'class' => 'someclass'

   You will have `<select name="..." class="someclass">`  whch allow you to use Prototype/JQuery/Native JS for catching this element and doing whatever you want.
2. 'input_renderer' => 'definition of renderer'

   This allow you to define own renderer for this element, so you can change all html-code, generated by standard dropdown renderer for your attribute.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm using. Thanks will give it a go and let you know.

Comment: You can find good example for input_renderer here: https://inchoo.net/magento/adding-magento-attribute-with-custom-input-renderer/

Comment: Tried it to no avail. I think I may be messing something else up. Are there any detailed beginner tutorials for this? All I found assume knowledge about structure, naming conventions, where things are etc.

Comment: I think you changed $installer->... part but don't reinstall extension after that. Magento don't call installation part if module already installed and have actual version. You need reintsall it or change version number and move changes to upgrade file. More details here: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/

Comment: Yes I have a file called mysql4-upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php and there I have the updates to BOTH class and input_renderer but nothing helps..
I tried removing my modules core_resource row to force a reinstall but that doesn't make these take effect either

Comment: Also forgot to mention, the version is also updated in config.xml and it reflects the changes in the database after refreshing Magento, cache is turned off and tried flushing it as well just in case.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, your answer and article was as close as I came to figuring it out though so I'll select it. What the article doesn't mention and expects you to know is that the `input_renderer` is in format off `namespace_modulename/path_to_renderer` where `path_to_renderer` is without the `Block_` folder